# Giving Multiple ip address of same n/w on two virtual nic

Tags: networking, ip, nic, route

running xen with 2 guests

i have been trying to assign public ip addresses to two virtual nic, one each which is sharing bridge networking with host.

tried this

```
Host x.x.116.2
```

created two nic on guest which is using same bridge with host

```
eth0 x.x.116.3
eth1 x.x.116.4
```

but at a time only one is active,how can i enable both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off just aliasing the .4 to the eth0 interface and not placing it on it's separate interface since they are the same subnet.

```
ifconfig eth0:1 x.x.116.4 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: mike could u tell me,why this will not work,if we assign ip of same sub net.

Comment: because you probably gave it a /24 so the kernel will send all traffic out eth0 for .4 and it won't like coming back in via eth0.. You can do it but it requires a lot of tricky `ip route` commands. Why are you even doing multiple interfaces anyway? If you use multiple ips on the same subnet.. it should be aliased

Comment: Interface aliases are deprecated, as is `ifconfig` on linux. The same effect can be achieved more naturally with `ip addr add x.x.116.4/24 dev eth0`.